# get_site_option / update_site_option - the main site and sub sites do not share the same storage

Tags: multisite, options

get_site_option / update_site_option is supposed to get / update an option for the current network (contrary to its name).

I have noticed that it works only for sub-sites, all sub-sites share the same settings storage, however, the "main" site does not (the initial site that is not a subdomain or subdir). Why is that?

Comment: I'm testing it on a installation that has only one network, the main site and the sub sites are on the same network.

Comment: Subsites do not share settings storage. Each subsite has its own options table in the DB.

Comment: I meant in the context of network storage. Subsites share network storage but the main site does not.

Comment: This should not be the case - and isn't the case in my tests. The primary site and the child sites can both use those functions and retrieve the same results. Is it possible you have a filter interfering somewhere?

Comment: Incidentally, the confusing naming is due to WP's changing terminology over time. `get_site_option` is in fact now just a wrapper for `get_network_option`.

Comment: This is a stock site but the setting comes from a third party plugin. I will check if it works for an option I define myself. Thanks.